# URL Shortener - .htaccess update

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A while ago I made a little URL shortener which basically just redirects the user to the 'long url'.

The script that does as such is -cleverly- named shorter.php.

So, my problem:

When I first made the shortener, I made an .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ shorter.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Which allowed me to rewrite: doma.in/s/VAR to doma.in/shorter.php?u=VAR, which in turn redirects to the page that is linked to the VAR.

Last week I realised I could also make my URL shortener like this: dome.in/VAR

This can also be done in .htaccess, as far as I know.

The problem comes for me when I still have to support the URL with 's/' in between 'doma.in' & 'VAR'.

Help appreciated, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `^s/` optional by using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:s/)?(.+)$ shorter.php?u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Added 2 `RewriteCond` to make sure you don't rewrite existing files and directories.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you maybe explain why? 
I don't understand the '?:s/' part. The '?' after the parenthesis I understand. Also, what does the QSA do?

Comment: `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. and `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group so that next group is still `$1` not `$2`.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html is good documentation on `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Haha, yes I know ;-) It said i had to wait.. Marked it as accepted now!